# Output on the basis of folder and file name

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have some directories structure like below, where the last folder name will be the current date changing everyday, as below:

```
D:\data\Backup\WINDOWSDATA\18-03-2015
D:\data\Backup\LINUXDATA\18-03-2015
D:\data\Backup\UBUNTUDATA\18-03-2015
```

Under each date folder (18-03-2015) there will be `maximum four .dat files` having different time stamps in their names, as given below:

```
BKP_DS_FETCHER_6AM.dat
BKP_DS_FETCHER_10AM.dat
BKP_DS_FETCHER_2PM.dat
BKP_DS_FETCHER_6PM.dat
```

I am trying to generate following results in an output.txt file on the basis of simple logic that is if .dat file is there for a particular time, there should come `Success` otherwise `Failed` in `output.txt` for example as below:

**output.txt:**

```
FOLDER_NAME       6AM       10AM     2PM       6PM
WINDOWSDATA       Success   Failed   Success   Success
LINUXDATA         Success   Success  Failed    Success
UBUNTUDATA        Failed    Success  Success   Success
```

Please can somebody help me show the way to achieve it (in Batch or Powershell) ?

Comment: The task seems to be a trival exercise of `Test-Path`. What have you got covered so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in PowerShell:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'

$basePath = 'D:\data\Backup\'
$outputPath = 'D:\data\Backup\output_' + $date + '.txt'

$baseFileName = 'BKP_DS_FETCHER_[HOUR].dat'
$hours = @( '6AM', '10AM', '2PM', '6PM' )


function Check-Folder( $folderName )
{
    $resultLine = New-Object -TypeName System.Object 
    $resultLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FOLDER_NAME' -Value $folderName

    foreach( $h in $script:hours )
    {
        $path = $script:basePath + $folderName + '\' + $script:date + '\' + $script:baseFileName.Replace('[HOUR]',$h)
        #Write-Host $path

        if( Test-Path -Path $path )
        {
            $resultLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $h -Value 'Success'
        }
        else
        {
            $resultLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $h -Value 'Failed'
        }
    }

    return $resultLine
}

$results = @()

$results += Check-Folder 'WINDOWSDATA'
$results += Check-Folder 'LINUXDATA'
$results += Check-Folder 'UBUNTUDATA'

$results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath $outputPath
```

Output will look like this:

```
FOLDER_NAME 6AM     10AM    2PM     6PM   
----------- ---     ----    ---     ---   
WINDOWSDATA Success Failed  Success Success
LINUXDATA   Failed  Failed  Failed  Failed
UBUNTUDATA  Failed  Success Failed  Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Push-Location D:\data\Backup
$todayDir = Get-Item (get-date -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($todayDir)
{
Push-Location $todayDir
$logResult = @{}
dir -Directory | foreach {
$logResult.($_.Name) = $_.Name | Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.dat' |
foreach {
           $isMatch = $_.Name -match 'BKP_DS_FETCHER_(?<hour>.*).dat$'
           if($isMatch) {
            $Matches.hour
           }
        }
    }

$hourProperties = ($logResult.Values | foreach {$_}) |  Sort-Object | Get-Unique 

$logResult.Keys | foreach {
$obj = New-Object pscustomobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FOLDER_NAME' -Value $_
foreach($p in $hourProperties) {
        $v=$null
        if($logResult[$_] -contains $p) { 
            $v = 'Success'
        }
        else {
            $v = 'Failed' 
        }
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $p -Value $v
    }

    $obj
    } | Format-Table 

    Pop-Location

}
Pop-Location
```

[image]